Why is the inverse of a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is also differentiable?
I came across a problem in my multivariable calculus studies whose proof I don't fully understand. The problem states:
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a differentiable and invertible function. Prove that $n = m$.
The proof goes as follows:
Note that $I = f \circ f^{-1}$, where $I$ is the identity map. Applying the chain rule, we have $Df(f^{-1}(x)) D(f^{-1})(x) = I$, which shows that the linear map $Df(f^{-1}(x))$ is invertible. Hence, $n = m$, by dimensions considertations.
My question is about the use of the chain rule in this proof. To apply the chain rule, $f^{-1}$ must be differentiable. Why is that guaranteed? Why is the inverse of a differentiable function necessarily differentiable?
Thank you in advance for your help!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule

Without additional assumptions on $f$, it's not generally true that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable. Take $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^3$, so $m=n=1$ in the problem statement. Then $f$ is differentiable and invertible, but $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is not differentiable because $(f^{-1})'(0)$ does not exist.

@AndreaAveni this works if $f'$ is nonzero throughout its domain. To the post owner: maybe was this was an additional assumption in the original problem statement? Not sure what the analogue of this for $m,n>1$ might look like.

What does it mean for $f$ to be invertible? Is the embedding of $\mathbb R^n$ in $\mathbb R^m$ invertible (where $n<m$?)

The essential point is the interpretation of "invertible". The minimal requirement is that $f$ is bijective so that the inverse function $f^{-1} : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ exists.
However, to apply the chain rule we have to know that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at least at one point $y_0 \in \mathbb R^m$.
Can we prove this? The inverse function theorem immediately comes to mind, but this only works if we already know that $n = m$. Besides this dimension assumption the inverse function theorem requires that $f$ is continuously differentiable in some open neighborhood of a point $x_0$ and has non-zero derivative $f'(x_0)$.
It is impossible that $f'(x_0) = 0$ for all $x_0$ (in that case $f$ would be constant), but the continuity of the derivative is not given in your question. But even if it were, we still miss the assumption that $n = m$.
Therefore I think that we must restate the problem as follows:

Let $f : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ be a differentiable bijection such that  $f^{-1} : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at least at one point $y_0 \in \mathbb R^m$. Prove that $n = m$.

